# Header of grid is not stable

Tags: javascript

My gridview's header is static. i have tried a js code and called it from the page load and its working as below.

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "CreateGridHeader", "javascript:CreateGridHeader()", True)
```

js will be,

```
function CreateGridHeader()
{
    var DataDivObj = document.getElementById("<%=DataDiv.ClientID%>");
    var DataGridObj = document.getElementById("<%=gridview.ClientID%>");
    var HeaderDivObj = document.getElementById("<%=HeaderDiv.ClientID%>");
     // other
}
```

now i want to apply this for other grid also. so i changed the js as,

```
function CreateGridHeader(DataDivObj,DataGridObj,HeaderDivObj)
{
     // other
}
```

and i called it from pageload as,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "CreateGridHeader", "javascript:CreateGridHeader('DataDiv', 'gridview', 'HeaderDiv')", True)
```

it is not working. but give me a code to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code. it will work.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "CreateGridHeader", "javascript:CreateGridHeader(" + DataDiv.ClientID + "," + gridview.ClientID + "," + HeaderDiv.ClientID + ")", True)
```